# Trata erro dentro do if JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou construindo uma calculadora, que nesse caso especifico, o usuário irá clicar em um botão e aparecerá uma equação da regra de três simples. Então ele irá substituir as variáveis da formula, que esta no `input`, e depois os valores foram inseridos na equação, o usuário irá clicar novamente no botão e quero que faça uma verificação onde se dentro do `input` contem uma equação valida ele retorne o resultado correto. Mas não consegui encontrar algo parecido na net sobre esse tipo de tratativa de erro. Agradeço pela ajuda.

Segue o `Javascript`:

```
function regraDeTresSimples(){
     var vis = document.calcform.visor;
     var resultado;
     if (vis.value == "" ) {
          document.calcform.visor.value = "x=(A*B)/C";
          document.getElementById("explicacao").src = "img/regradetressimples.JPG";
          document.getElementById("explicacao").alt = "Aprenda a calcular regra de     três";
          document.getElementById("explicacao").title = "Posição de cada variavel  dentro da regra de três simples";
     } else if(isNaN(vis.value)){
          resultado = eval(vis.value);
     }
     vis.value = resultado;
}
```

Segue `HTML`:

```
<form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value=""/>
    <input type="button" name="dividir" class="formula" value="R3s" title="Regra de Três simples" onclick="regraDeTresSimples()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem qual o erro que você quer que seja tratado.

Comment: Quero saber nessa parte do codigo: `if(isNaN(vis.value))` se não houver um erro ele possa executar a função`resultado = eval(vis.value);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, pessoalmente eu separaria os inputs para você ter mais controle na validação, e evitar o máximo possível a utilização da função `eval`.

Segue um pequeno exemplo de como você poderia fazer utilizando vários inputs e montando uma representação visual da expressão em html (bem precária aqui por ser apenas um exemplo).

Na função `validado()` você poderia em vez de apenas retornar um true/false, também atualizar algum campo de mensagem na tela para o usuário visualizar o que ele fez de errado.

Espero ter ajudado.

```js
(function() {

var btnCalcular = document.getElementById("calcular");

var A = document.getElementById("A");
var B = document.getElementById("B");
var C = document.getElementById("C");

var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

btnCalcular.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(validado()) {
    resultado.textContent = (A.value*B.value)/C.value;
  } else {
    alert("Inválido!");
  }
});

function validado() {
  return A.value && B.value && C.value
}

})();
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    X = ( <input id="A" type="number" /> * <input id="B" type="number" /> ) / <input id="C" type="number" /> 
  </p>
  <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
  
  <span id="resultado"></span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Israel muito obg pela dica vou verificar e te falo.